Проблема с обнаружением ключевого слова в pvporcupine
Я использую библиотеку pvporcupine для обнаружения ключевого слова "Hey Sasha" через микрофон в Python. После запуска кода, консоль выводит "Listening for keyword...", но при произнесении ключевого слова ничего не происходит. Я проверил, что микрофон и библиотека работают нормально. Как можно исправить эту проблему?
Спасибо!
import pvporcupine
import sounddevice as sd

def detect_wake_word(keyword_path):
    handle = pvporcupine.create(access_key="access_key", keyword_paths=[keyword_path], sensitivities=[0.5])

    try:
        print(f'Listening for keyword...')
        while True:
            pcm = sd.rec(int(handle.frame_length), samplerate=handle.sample_rate, channels=1, dtype='int16')
            sd.wait()
            pcm = pcm.flatten()
            result = handle.process(pcm)
            
            if result >= 0:
                print(f'Detected keyword')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Detection stopped by user.")

    finally:
        if handle is not None:
            handle.delete()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    keyword_path = "wake_word.ppn"
    detect_wake_word(keyword_path)

